# How do I connect multiple excel sheets from python to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, excel

> I am trying to connect/load multiple excel sheets under the same workbook from Python into MySQL and I haven't seen any threads answer this. Please help :)

This is what I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
import mysql.connector


db = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', passwd='Adm1n__$$', host='Localhost', database ='vmg')

user_columns =['RowID', 'OrderID', 'OrderDate', 'OrderPriority', 'OrderQuantity', 'Sales', 'Discount',
'ShipMode', 'Profit', 'UnitPrice', 'ShippingCost', 'CustomerName', 'Province', 'Region', 'CustomerSegment',
'ProductCategory', 'ProductSubCategory', 'ProductName', 'ProductContainer', 'ProductBaseMargin', 'Date']

barget_store = pd.ExcelFile('D:/Users/vguevara/ExternalScripts/Colaberry/PythonClass/barget_store.xlsx')
df1 = pd.read_excel(xlsx, 'Orders', header = None, names = user_columns)
df2 = pd.read_excel(xlsx, 'Returns')
df3 = pd.read_excel(xlsx, 'Users')
barget_store.to_sql('barget_store', engine, if_exists='replace')
```

I keep getting an error code that says:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "D:\Users\vguevara\ExternalScripts\Colaberry\FinalLabProject.py", line >31, in 
>      barget_store.to_sql('barget_store', engine, if_exists='replace')
>   AttributeError: 'ExcelFile' object has no attribute 'to_sql'

what am I missing?

Comment: You should probably using the following code `barget_store.to_sql('barget_store', con=engine, if_exists='replace')`. I've added "**con=**" for the engine

Comment: @Gangula  didn't work, thank you tho :)

Comment: What is `xlsx`, how is `engine` defined and what are `df1`, `df2` and `df3` for? Please make sure your examples show *only* relevant code, but also *all* relevent code. As for your error, `to_sql` is a method of `DataFrame` objects, but `barget_store` is an `ExcelFile` object. You'll have to call [`parse`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html) on it first.